# Django TypeError at /url/ get() missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm having trouble with this because in my localhost the url can receive 2 optional arguments, the url can receive just one but not both.

testing the route locally works, but not when in production, i get this error:

```
TypeError at /url/
get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'
```

in the urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('url/<int:pk>', Class.as_view()),
    path('url/', Class.as_view()),
    path('url/<int:option>',Class.as_view()),
    #etc... more routes below
```

in my Class.py file:

```
class Class(APIView):

    def get(self, request, pk = None, option = None):
    # more code below...
```

Note: i change the name of the class & routes for job reasons...
Not sure why works locally but not in server production, any ideas? what i'm missing?

Comment: Did you remove the `*.pyc` files?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem gonna check

Comment: This `path('url/', Class.as_view()),`  is not required in urlpattern. You already have `path('url/<int:pk>', Class.as_view())`, for Class view. So remove that.

Comment: Turns out it was a problem with gitlab pipelines cache, not with the code itself.